# перевод из двоичной в десятичную python

Tags: python

Суть задачи:на вход функции подаются два положительных целочисленных числа, нужно вывести их сумму в двоичной системе.

Написал код, с числами порядка 10^4-10^6 работает, с очень большими числами, как в примере ниже работает лишь на половину, т.е сначала идут все 0, а потом уже часть числа конвертируется, не могу понять в чем ошибка.

```py
def add_binary(a,b):
    summ = a + b
    ostatok = int(summ % 2)
    delimoe = int((summ - ostatok)/2)
    answer = [str(int(ostatok))]
    while(delimoe > 0):
        ostatok = int(delimoe % 2)
        delimoe = int((delimoe - ostatok)/2)
        answer.append(str(int(ostatok)))
    answer.reverse()    
    answerstring = ''.join(answer)
    return(answerstring)
add_binary(996658199706798567539,711895482903627032739)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/699891/4928642

Answer (score 4):

У вас возникала ошибка округления в этой формуле `int((summ - ostatok)/2)`

Используйте целочисленное деление, оно есть в Питоне.

```
def add_binary(a,b):

    summ = a + b
    ostatok = summ % 2
    delimoe = summ//2
    answer = [ostatok]
    while(delimoe > 0):
        ostatok = delimoe % 2
        delimoe = delimoe//2
        answer.append(ostatok)
    answer.reverse()    
    answerstring = ''.join(str(e) for e in answer)
    return(answerstring)

print(add_binary(996658199706798567539,711895482903627032739))
```

Comment: @Эникейщик Почему?

Comment: Я проверил, у вас не правильно https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=996658199706798567539%2B711895482903627032739+to+binary+

Comment: Вывод программы 10111001001111011110010000010100000011101011111111010101001100100010110
Вывод Wolfram
2^^10111001001111011110010000010100000011101011111111010101001100100010110

Comment: пардон, не то скопировал

Comment: Блин, я свой код проверял через ``print("{0:b}".format(99665819970679856753937+711895482903627032739))`` вместо того, чтобы сразу сумму туда вписать. А в таком виде неправильный результат выдает.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/SyJ81L

```
x = int(input()) + int(input())
print("{0:b}".format(x))
```

Comment: В python также есть функция `bin()`, которая возвращает двоичное представление передаваемого ей числа. Но, раз человек пишет алгоритм, видимо, ему нужно решить эту задачу самостоятельно ;)

Comment: @Евгений, ну с алгоритмом ему вроде уже ответили.